# Understanding the structure of 是谁打电话过来呢

Tags: grammar, direction-complement

I know that 是谁打电话过来呢 means "who is calling?" but I don't know how to parse it:

- why is 是 at the beginning?
- not sure about the meaning of 过来. Is 电话过来 a standard combination?
- why 呢? I thought it is used for "what about...?" questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This sentence has an abbreviated 的 in 是誰打電話過來的呢. 是～的 is a very common construction that you must remember; it is used *for emphasis*. In your sentence, you would like to emphasise *who* called. Basically, 誰打電話過來 (who called) is the question without any emphasis.
2. 打～過來 should be seen together, not 電話過來. For details please see my explanation on the auxiliary verb 來 [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/42926/difference-between-%E4%BB%96%E5%B8%A6%E6%9D%A5%E4%BA%86%E5%BE%88%E5%A4%9A%E8%A1%A3%E6%9C%8D-and-%E4%BB%96%E5%B8%A6%E5%BE%88%E5%A4%9A%E8%A1%A3%E6%9C%8D%E6%9D%A5/42927#42927). In general, 來 may (1) indicate an observed movement caused by the main verb (打) towards the speaker; or (2) the start (or in a more abstract sense, consequence) of the action caused by the main verb. Here, it emphasises someone called as if the call *approached* the speaker. A more semantically accurate translation of 打～過來 is 'to call here'.
3. Your statement on 呢 is irrelevant in this situation. While 嗎 is a question particle for yes/no questions, 呢 is a question particle for 5W1H words, in this case 'who'. Therefore,

> ```
> 是誰打電話過來的嗎（✖）
> 是誰打電話過來的呢（✓）
> Who is it that called?
>
> 是他打電話過來的呢（✖）
> 是他打電話過來的嗎（✓）
> Is it he who called?
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I know about the 是～的 construction and I suspected that my example was related. I just didn't know that the final 的 can be omitted. Regarding my last question, I thought that 谁 was enough to make that sentence a question.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderVorobiev, you are right, both 是誰打電話過來？ and 是誰打電話過來的？ are grammatically sound, despite the absence of a question particle. You may see here for when to use 呢: https://eastasiastudent.net/china/mandarin/four-uses-呢/. As for 的 omission, it is fine unless the ～的 indicates possession, such as 是我的 (lit. is mine); in that case 是我 would mean differently (lit. is me).

Answer (score 2):

[是谁] = [(it) is who]

*打 = dials*

*电话 = phone*

[打电话] = [makes phone call]

*过 = over*

*来 = toward here*

[过来] (verb particle indicates the direction of the verb)

[呢?] (particle indicate a question, but not a yes or no question )

是谁打电话过来 = who makes the phone call (coming in/ toward here) = who called (in) here?

Similarly:

是谁打电话过去 = who makes the phone call (going out/ toward there) = who called (out) there?

Answer (score 0):

1.这句话是正确的， 是谁=谁，用于句子开头都是可以的。
2.从打电话一方来说，是打过去；从接电话一方是打过来。
2.呢是语气词，在不同句子中不同含义。可以用于选择疑问句。